# JavaFX scene recording

Tags: javafx-8, video-recording

Yesterday as I was working on my game and I decided I wanted to include some sort of a video showing sneak peaks of the themes and tutorials and such. I then decided to check how to record my scene or nodes. After looking around i concluded there was no easy way to do it so I decided to make my own utility which I want to share with all of you.

Please know I am more or less a beginner and I havent been coding for long. I know it is probably not properly done and that it can be done in much better ways. Anyways here it goes.

```
/*
 * JavaFX SceneCaptureUtility 2016/07/02
 *
 * The author of this software "Eudy Contreras" grants you ("Licensee")
 * a non-exclusive, royalty free, license to use,modify and redistribute this
 * software in source and binary code form.
 *
 * Please be aware that this software is simply part of a personal test
 * and may in fact be unstable. The software in its current state is not
 * considered a finished product and has plenty of room for improvement and
 * changes due to the range of different approaches which can be used to
 * achieved the desired result of the software.
 *
 * BEWARE that because of the nature of this software and because of the way
 * this software functions the ability of this software to be able to operate
 * without probable malfunction is strictly based on factors such as the amount
 * of processing power the system running the software has, and the resolution of
 * the screen being recorded. The amount of nodes on the scene will have an impact
 * as well as the size and recording rate to which this software will be subjected
 * to. IN CASE OF MEMORY RELATED PROBLEMS SUCH AS BUT NOT LIMITEd TO LACK OF REMAINING
 * HEAP SPACE PLEASE CONSIDER LOWERING THE RESOLUTION OF THE SCENE BEING RECORDED.
 *
 * BEWARE STABILITY ISSUES MAY ARISE!
 * BEWARE SAVING AND LOADING THE RECORDED VIDEO MAY TAKE TIME DEPENDING ON YOUR SYSTEM
 * 
 * PLEASE keep track of the console for useful information and feedback
 */

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.util.Duration;

 * @author Eudy Contreras
 *
 * This program records a javaFX scene by taking continuous snapshots of the scene
 * which are than stored and saved to a predefined destination. The program allows the
 * user to save and retrieve the frame based videos make by this program which can
 * then be play on a specified layer or "screen".

public class SceneCaptureUtility {

    private int frame = 0; // The current frame which is being displayed
    private int timer = 0; // recording timer.
    private int record_time; // Amount of time the recorder will record
    private int counter = 0;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private float frameRate = 60.0f; 

    private long capture_rate = (long) (1000f / frameRate); // Rate at which the recorder will recored. Default rate: 60FPS

    private PlaybackSettings playSettings;

    private Double frameCap = 1.0 / frameRate; // Framerate at which the recorded video will play
    private Double video_size_scale = 1.0; // Scale of the video relative to its size: 0.5 = half, 2.0 = double the size
    private Double bounds_scale_X = 0.5; // Scale factor for scaling relative to assigned or obtained resolution
    private Double bounds_scale_Y = 0.5;

    private Boolean saveFrames = false; //If true saves the individual frames of the video as images
    private Boolean loadFrames = false; //If true allows retrieving previously saved frames for playback
    private Boolean allowRecording = false;
    private Boolean allowPlayback = false;
    private Boolean showIndicators = false;

    private Pane indicator_layer;
    private Pane video_screen;

    private Scene scene;

    private Timeline videoPlayer;

    private ArrayList<Image> recorded_frames; //Stores recorded frames
    private ArrayList<ImageView> video_frames; //Stores frames for playback
    private ArrayList<byte[]> temp_frames; //Stores frames for saving

    private final SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    private final Indicator recording = new Indicator(Color.RED, " Recording..");
    private final Indicator playing = new Indicator(Color.GREEN, " Playing..");
    private final Indicator idle = new Indicator(Color.YELLOW, "paused..");

    private final String VIDEO_NAME = "recording4.FXVideo";
    private final String FRAME_NAME = "image";
    private final String DIRECTORY_NAME = "Snake Game Videos"+ File.separator;
    private final String PATH_ROOT = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop" + File.separator +DIRECTORY_NAME;
    private final String FILE_EXTENSION = "jpg";
    private final String PATH_FRAME = PATH_ROOT + FRAME_NAME;
    private final String PATH_VIDEO = PATH_ROOT + VIDEO_NAME;

    /**
     * Constructs a scene capture utility with a default scene, a pane which 
     * will be used to diplay the state indicators, the amount of time which
     * the recorder will be running and a condition to whether or not the indicators
     * will be shown.
     * @param scene: scene which will be recored.
     * @param indicatorLayer: layer which will be used to show the state indicators.
     * @param record_time: time in minutes for which the recorder will be recording
     * @param showIndicators: condition which determines if the indicators will be shown.
     */
    public SceneCaptureUtility(Scene scene, Pane indicatorLayer, int record_time, boolean showIndicators) {
        this.scene = scene;
        this.width = (int) scene.getWidth();
        this.height = (int) scene.getHeight();
        this.showIndicators = showIndicators;
        this.record_time = record_time * 60;
        this.initStorages(indicatorLayer);
        this.loadRecording();
        this.scaleResolution(0, 0, false);
    }
    /*
     * Initializes the list used to store the captured frames.
     */
    private void initStorages(Pane layer) {
        if(showIndicators)
            this.indicator_layer = layer;
        video_frames = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        recorded_frames = new ArrayList<Image>();
        temp_frames = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    }
    /**
     * loads recordings and or frames from a specified location
     */
    private void loadRecording(){
        if (loadFrames) {
            loadFromFile();
        } else {
            retrieveRecording();
        }
    }
    /*
     * Resets the list
     */
    private void resetStorage() {
        if (video_frames != null)
            video_frames.clear();
        if (recorded_frames != null)
            recorded_frames.clear();
        if (video_screen != null)
            video_screen.getChildren().clear();
    }
    /**
     * Method which when called will start recording the given scene.
     */
    public void startRecorder() {
        if (!allowRecording) {
            resetStorage();
            if(showIndicators)
            showIndicator(indicator_layer.getChildren(), recording);
            videoRecorder();
            allowRecording(true);
            logState("Recording...");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Method which when called will stop the recording
     */
    public void stopRecorder() {
        if (allowRecording) {
            if(showIndicators)
            showIndicator(indicator_layer.getChildren(), idle);
            allowRecording(false);
            logState("Recording stopped");
            logState("Amount of recorded frames: " + recorded_frames.size());
            processVideo();
            saveVideo();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Method which when called will start playback of the recorded video onto
     * a given screen or layer.
     * @param output_screen: layer used to display the video
     * @param settings: video settings that determine the playback conditions.
     */
    public void starPlayer(Pane output_screen, PlaybackSettings settings) {
        video_screen = output_screen;
        playSettings = settings;
        if(showIndicators)
        showIndicator(indicator_layer.getChildren(), playing);
        if (video_frames.size() > 0) {
            logState("Video playback..");
            resetPlayback();
            if (videoPlayer == null)
                videoPlayer();
            else {
                videoPlayer.play();
            }
            allowPlayback(true);
        }
        else{
            logState("Nothing to play!");
        }

    }
    /**
     * Method which when called will stop the playback of the video
     */
    public void stopPlayer() {
        if(showIndicators)
        showIndicator(indicator_layer.getChildren(), idle);
        if (videoPlayer != null)
            videoPlayer.stop();
        logState("Playback stopped");
        allowPlayback(false);
    }
    /*
     * Method which creates a task which records the video at
     * a specified rate for a specifed time 
     */
    private void videoRecorder() {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                while (true) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (allowRecording && record_time > 0) {
                                recorded_frames.add(create_frame());
                            }

                            recordingTimer();
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(capture_rate);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    /*
     * Method which creates a timeline which plays the video 
     * at a specified frameRate onto a given screen or layer.
     */
    private void videoPlayer() {

        videoPlayer = new Timeline();
        videoPlayer.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(frameCap), 

                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                        if (allowPlayback) {

                            playbackVideo();

                        }
                    }
                });

        videoPlayer.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        videoPlayer.play();

    }
    **/**
     * Calls to this method will decreased the time left on the 
     * recording every second until the recording time reaches
     * zero. this will cause the recording to stop.
     */**
    private void recordingTimer() {
        timer++;
        if (allowRecording && timer >= frameRate) {
            record_time -= 1;
            timer = 0;
            if (record_time <= 0) {
                record_time = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * A call to this method will add the recorded frames to the video list 
     * making them reading for playback.
     */
    private void processVideo() {
        logState("Processing video...");
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < recorded_frames.size(); i++) {
                    video_frames.add(new ImageView(recorded_frames.get(i)));
                }
                logState("Video has been processed.");
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    /**
     * Call to this method will play the video on the given screen
     * adding a removing frames.
     * @return: screen in which the frames are being rendered
     */
    private final Pane playbackVideo() {
        if (video_screen.getChildren().size() > 0)
            video_screen.getChildren().remove(0);
        video_screen.getChildren().add(video_frames.get(frame));
        frame += 1;
        if (frame > video_frames.size() - 1) {
            if(playSettings == PlaybackSettings.CONTINUOUS_REPLAY){
                frame = 0;
            }
            else if(playSettings == PlaybackSettings.PLAY_ONCE){
                frame = video_frames.size() - 1;
                allowPlayback = false;
            }
        }
        return video_screen;
    }

    public void setVideoScale(double scale) {
        this.video_size_scale = scale;
    }
    /**
     * A called to this method will scale the video
     * to a given scale.
     * @param scale: new scale of the video. 1.0 is normal
     * 0.5 is half and 2.0 is twice the size.
     */
    public void scaleVideo(double scale) {
        this.video_size_scale = scale;
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                if (video_frames.size() > 0) {
                    logState("Scaling video...");
                    for (int i = 0; i < video_frames.size(); i++) {
                        video_frames.get(i).setFitWidth(video_frames.get(i).getImage().getWidth() * video_size_scale);
                        video_frames.get(i).setFitHeight(video_frames.get(i).getImage().getHeight() * video_size_scale);
                    }
                    logState("Video has been scaled!");
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    /**
     * A called to this method will attempt to prepare the video and or frames
     * for saving
     */
    private void saveVideo() {
        File root = new File(PATH_ROOT);
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                root.mkdirs();
                for (int i = 0; i < recorded_frames.size(); i++) {
                    saveToFile(recorded_frames.get(i));
                }
                saveRecording(temp_frames);
                logState("Amount of compiled frames: " + temp_frames.size());
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    /**
     * A called to this method will add the frames store is array list 
     * to the video list.
     * @param list: list containing the byte arrays of the frames
     */
    private void loadFrames(ArrayList<byte[]> list) {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                logState("loading frames...");
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    video_frames.add(byteToImage(list.get(i)));
                }
                logState("frames have been added!");
                scaleVideo(video_size_scale);
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    /**
     * Method which when called will add and display a indicator.
     * @param rootPane: list to which the indicator will be added
     * @param indicator: indicator to be displayed
     */
    private void showIndicator(ObservableList<Node> rootPane, Indicator indicator) {
        rootPane.removeAll(playing, idle, recording);
        indicator.setTranslateX(width - ScaleX(150));
        indicator.setTranslateY(ScaleY(100));
        rootPane.add(indicator);
    }
    /**
     * Calls to this method will save each frame if conditions are met
     * and will also store each frame into a list of byte arrays.
     * @param image: image to be saved to file and or converted and store as
     * a byte array.
     */
    private void saveToFile(Image image) {
        counter += 1;
        BufferedImage BImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
        temp_frames.add(ImageToByte(BImage));
        if (saveFrames) {
            File video = new File(PATH_FRAME + counter + "." + FILE_EXTENSION);
            try {
                ImageIO.write(BImage, FILE_EXTENSION, video);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Method which when called loads images from a predefined 
     * directory in order to play them as a video.
     */
    private void loadFromFile() {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 1; i < 513; i++) {
                    File video = new File(PATH_FRAME + i + "." + FILE_EXTENSION);
                    video_frames.add(new ImageView(new Image(video.toURI().toString())));
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    /**
     * Method which when called will attemp to save the video 
     * to a specified directory.
     * @param list
     */
    private void saveRecording(ArrayList<byte[]> list) {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                File root = new File(PATH_ROOT);
                File video = new File(PATH_VIDEO);
                video.delete();
                logState("Saving video...");
                try {
                    root.mkdirs();
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(PATH_VIDEO);
                    BufferedOutputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut);
                    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(bufferedStream);
                    outputStream.writeObject(list);
                    outputStream.close();
                    fileOut.close();
                    logState("Video saved.");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logState("Failed to save, I/O exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    /**
     * Method which when called attempts to retrieve the video
     * from a specified directory
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void retrieveRecording() {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                File root = new File(PATH_ROOT);
                File video = new File(PATH_VIDEO);

                if (root.exists() && video.exists()) {
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(PATH_VIDEO);
                        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
                        temp_frames = (ArrayList<byte[]>) inputStream.readObject();
                        inputStream.close();
                        fileIn.close();
                        logState("\nLoading video");
                        loadFrames(temp_frames);
                    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        logState("Failed to load! " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    logState("Nothing to load.");
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

    }

    /**
     * Method which when call creates a frame or snapshot of the 
     * given scene to be recorded.
     * @return: frame taken from the scene.
     */
    private synchronized Image create_frame() {
        WritableImage wi = new WritableImage(width, height);
        if (scene != null)
            scene.snapshot(wi);
        try {
            return wi;
        } finally {
            wi = null;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Method which when called crates a frame or snapshot of the 
     * given node.
     * @param node: node to be recorded
     * @return: image or frame of recorded node.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private synchronized Image create_node_frame(Node node) {
        parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        WritableImage wi = new WritableImage((int)node.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth(), (int) node.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());
        node.snapshot(parameters, wi);
        return wi;

    }
    /**
     * Method which when called will create a scale relative to a base
     * and current resolution.
     * @param scaleX: x scaling factor used for manual scaling
     * @param scaleY: y scaling factor used for manual scaling
     * @param manualScaling: determines if a manual scaling will be applied or not
     */
    public void scaleResolution(double scaleX, double scaleY, boolean manualScaling) {
        double resolutionX = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();
        double resolutionY = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();
        double baseResolutionX = 1920;
        double baseResolutionY = 1080;
        bounds_scale_X = baseResolutionX / resolutionX;
        bounds_scale_Y = baseResolutionY / resolutionY;
        if(manualScaling==true){
            bounds_scale_X = bounds_scale_X*scaleX;
            bounds_scale_Y = bounds_scale_Y*scaleY;
        }
    }

    public void allowRecording(boolean state) {
        allowRecording = state;
        logState("allowed recording: " + state);
    }

    public void allowPlayback(boolean state) {
        allowPlayback = state;
        logState("allowed playback: " + state);
    }

    public void setLocation(double x, double y) {
        video_screen.setTranslateX(x);
        video_screen.setTranslateY(y);
    }
    public void setDimensions(double width, double height) {
        video_screen.setPrefSize(width, height);;
    }
    public void resetPlayback() {
        this.frame = 0;
    }

    public double Scale(double value) {
        double newSize = value * (bounds_scale_X + bounds_scale_Y)/2;
        return newSize;
    }

    public double ScaleX(double value) {
        double newSize = value * bounds_scale_X;
        return newSize;
    }

    public double ScaleY(double value) {
        double newSize = value * bounds_scale_Y;
        return newSize;
    }

    public double getVideoWidth(){
        if(!video_frames.isEmpty())
            return video_frames.get(0).getImage().getWidth() * video_size_scale;
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public double getVideoHeight(){
        if(!video_frames.isEmpty())
        return video_frames.get(0).getImage().getWidth() * video_size_scale;
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String loadResource(String image) {
        String url = PATH_ROOT + image;
        return url;
    }
    /**
     * Method which converts a bufferedimage to byte array
     * @param image: image to be converted
     * @return: byte array of the image
     */
    public final byte[] ImageToByte(BufferedImage image) {

        byte[] imageInByte = null;
        try {
            if (image != null) {
                ImageIO.write(image, FILE_EXTENSION, byteOutput);
                imageInByte = byteOutput.toByteArray();
                byteOutput.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            return imageInByte;
        } finally {
            byteOutput.reset();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Method which converts a byte array to a Imageview
     * @param data: byte array to be converted.
     * @return: imageview of the byte array
     */
    public final ImageView byteToImage(byte[] data) {
        BufferedImage newImage = null;
        ImageView imageView = null;
        Image image = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            newImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(newImage, null);
            imageView = new ImageView(image);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageView;
    }

    private void logState(String state) {
        System.out.println("JAVA_FX SCREEN RECORDER: " + state);
    }

    public enum PlaybackSettings {
        CONTINUOUS_REPLAY, PLAY_ONCE,
    }

    /**
     * Class which crates a simple indicator which can be 
     * used to display a recording or playing state
     * @author Eudy Contreras
     *
     */
    private class Indicator extends HBox {
        public Indicator(Color color, String message) {
            Circle indicator = new Circle(Scale(15), color);
            Text label = new Text(message);
            label.setFont(Font.font("", FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, Scale(20)));
            label.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, null, null)));
            getChildren().addAll(indicator, label);
        }
    }
}
```

**If you have any suggestions of things that will make this program more effecient please share with me. Thanks**

Comment: While this is interesting, SO is not the place for such things... Post it on github, and maybe post a link on the reddit.com/r/javafx or even reddit.com/r/java

Comment: @Eudy Conteras very good project.. i tried that!Keep on it.

Comment: For feedback on design, efficiency, performance, coding style etc, you may wish to post to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as it is on topic there (and I encourage you to do so).  Nicely written code btw.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. I will follow all your advice. =)